# Godot: Getting a node results in Nil Value

Tags: timer, get, game-development, godot, onready

i am trying to get into Godot. In my project i want to access a Timer called Duration Timer in the Dash Script attached to the Dash Node.

[Screenshot - Godot get Duration Timer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFOXj.png)

Already, i tried 3 ways of accessing the Node seen in line 4,5 and 6 of the screenshot.

```
onready var duration_timer = $DurationTimer
#onready var duration_timer = get_node("DurationTimer")
#onready var duration_timer = get_node("Movement/Dash/DurationTimer")
```

All 3 lines result in the highlighted errormessage

> "Invalid set index 'wait_time' (on base:
> 'Nil') with value of type 'int'.

The error appears in line 14 by trying to set a wait_time to the Timer element.

```
duration_timer.wait_time = 1
```

Does someone have a clue why i cant get the Timer element?

Comment: I can only guess you are running the code `duration_timer.wait_time = 1` at a time `duration_timer` is not set. Probably not set *yet*. So, where are you calling that code? Also, does it work if you do `$DurationTimer.wait_time = 1`? *By the way `get_node("Movement/Dash/DurationTimer")` is wrong.* Edit: is the code in movement or in dash? In the image I see `get_node("Dash")` which suggest that the code is in movement, in that it should be `get_node("Dash/DurationTimer")`.

Comment: Hey Teraot, thanks for your comment. The code you see in the screenshot is attached to the Dash node. $DurationTimer.wait_time = 1 leads to the same error: Invalid set index 'wait_time' (on base: 'null instance') with value of type 'int'. Yeah ive been playing for a while now with different notations for getting the timer and i still cant get it to work. The start_dash function is called from Player.gd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is causing the problem.

I do not think `get_node("DurationTimer")` or `$DurationTimer` are wrong. But if that is the problem, we can solve it by using a `NodePath`:

```
export var duration_timer_path:NodePath
onready var duration_timer = get_node(duration_timer_path)
```

Then set the `NodePath` from the inspector panel.

---

If the path is not wrong. It could be that the code is running before `_ready`. or that something (I don't know what) removed the timer or set it to null. *You can add an breakpoint and check on the remote tab of the scene tree panel when the game is running from the editor, to see if the timer is there.*

We can sidestep the problem by making a new timer if we don't have one. For example:

```
if not is_instance_valid(duration_timer):
    duration_timer = Timer.new()
    duration_timer.name = "DurationTimer"
    add_child(duration_timer)

# use duration_timer here
```

However, if the timer is there but we had failed to get it, we would have two timers in the scene tree. *You could also check in the remote tab of the scene tree panel if this resulted in two timers.*

So, let us try to get the node again, in case we failed the first time. And let us put it all in a method. Something like this:

```
func get_duration_timer() -> Timer:
    if is_instance_valid(duration_timer):
        return duration_timer

    duration_timer = get_node("DurationTimer") # or use a NodePath
    if is_instance_valid(duration_timer):
        return duration_timer

    duration_timer = Timer.new()
    duration_timer.name = "DurationTimer"
    add_child(duration_timer)
    return duration_timer
```

---

In fact, if we are in this scenario, then `onready` is not helping us. So we could have `duration_timer` defined without `onready` and without initialization. And always use the method to get the timer.

If we are going to always use the method, why not let the method add the timer instead of adding it in the scene tree? We could then remove the step of trying to get it:

```
func get_duration_timer() -> Timer:
    if is_instance_valid(duration_timer):
        return duration_timer

    duration_timer = Timer.new()
    duration_timer.name = "DurationTimer"
    add_child(duration_timer)
    return duration_timer
```

What we have here is a lazy initialization pattern: The timer is created when we first need it, on demand, not before.

Comment: Hey Theraot, thank you again. Adding the timer by code works just fine. Im gonna use this approach for now but i still dont get why i am not able to get the DurationTimer element i added manually in the Scene tree. `export var duration_timer_path:NodePath` and assigning the node via the ui doesnt do the job.